# Search replace value in a csv from a csv file

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to replace values in a specific column (first one) from a csv file.

I would like to use a csv file that contains values to replace.

Right now I am able to use this:

```
text = open("input.csv", "r", encoding="ISO-8859-1")
text = ''.join([i for i in text]) \
        .replace("1stvaluetoreplace","zzzzzzzz") \
        .replace("2ndvaluetoreplace","zzzaaa")
x = open("output.csv","w")
x.writelines(text)
x.close()
```

Instead of adding all values to replace in my Python script, is it possible to load values from another csv that contains the following?

```
"1stvaluetoreplace","zzzzzzzz"
"2ndvaluetoreplace","zzzaaa"
```

Comment: Yes, why not? Just open a third file.

Comment: text2 = open("replace.csv", "r", encoding="ISO-8859-1")

text = ''.join([i for i in text2]).replace

something like this would work?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it would be possible. For example like this:

```
text = open("input.csv", "r", encoding="ISO-8859-1")
text = ''.join([i for i in text]) 
replacelist = open("replace.csv","r").readlines()
for r in replacelist:
    r = r.split(",")
    text.replace(r[0],r[1])
x = open("output.csv","w")
x.writelines(text)
x.close()
```

BUT... The whole approach doesn't feel good. I'd parse CSV first and then handle it as object, not as a big string.

Comment: it's not replacing. My file has values like this:
sku;title;details

replace.csv has values like
value1,example

Any clue why it does not work?

Comment: Add some debug in for loop. For example, print `r` after it has been split. So you can see that it really has values you want.

Comment: Yea, i've fixed it. The big problem is that I need to only replace exact match strings and with replace method it replaces everything. I cannot set a delimiter.
Like when my input.csv contains ciao123 and ciao12345 and my replace.csv only has to replace "ciao123" with "ok", ciao12345 should not become ok45